# Positioning a span horizontally when window is resized

Tags: css

I have a span that I've positioned using the below code:

```
#Header .NavTabs .tabLevel1 { 
    position:relative; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    clear:left; 
    height:auto; 
    z-index: 0; 
    text-align:center; 
    top: -90px; 
    left: 600px;
}​
```

I need it positioned exactly where it is now horizontally in relation to the screen. However, whenever I shrink the browser window horizontally, because I've set left: 600px; it isn't staying where I need it to. Is there an alternative way to position it left: 600px; but adjust it's position automatically depending on the screensize?

[EDIT] I'm stupid. Got the answer. I did this:

```
#Header .NavTabs .tabLevel1 { 
    position:relative; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    clear:left; 
    height:auto; 
    z-index: 0; 
    text-align:center; 
    top: -85px; 
    margin-left: 51.5%;
}​
```

Comment: can you give more context like the html, a working example, where is this span suppose to be?

Comment: @MrLister Oops, haha thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the visible width (vw) instead of a fixed number of pixels. This will work better with different sized screens and resolutions.

So the line would be left: 50vw;

Comment: Simon, thanks! This kind of works as long as the browser window has been resized to something very small, but when in full screen, it is far to the right of where it needs to be :(. Is there a way to do like, a margin left percentage?

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid. Got the answer. I did this:

```
#Header .NavTabs .tabLevel1 { 
    position:relative; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    clear:left; h
    eight:auto; 
    z-index: 0; 
    text-align:center; 
    top: -85px; 
    margin-left: 51.5%;
}​
```